# Where is the keyword 'cast' in JPQL defined?

Tags: jpql

I was looking up the definition of 'cast' in JPQL, https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf - but I could not find it.

Do you know where it is defined?

Cheers,
Kai